# State Area for 2010 Census AREALAND variable not found

Tags: api, us-census, python

I was following [this](https://campus.datacamp.com/courses/analyzing-us-census-data-in-python/decennial-census-of-population-and-housing?ex=5) tutorial for requesting from the 2010 Decennial Census. It specifies the following code for printing a list of state names ("NAME"), state areas ("AREALAND"), and state total populations ("P001001"):

```
import requests


HOST = "https://api.census.gov/data"
year = "2010"
dataset = "dec/sf1"


base_url = "/".join([HOST, year, dataset])

predicates = {}


get_vars = ["NAME", "AREALAND", "P001001"]

predicates["get"] = ",".join(get_vars)


predicates["for"] = "state:*"

col_names = ["name", "total_pop", "state"]
r = requests.get(base_url, params = predicates)

print (r.text)
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

`error: error: unknown variable 'AREALAND'`

Looking at the [2010 Decennial Census Variable List](https://api.census.gov/data/2010/dec/sf1/variables.html) I don't see 'AREALAND' listed. Has the API been changed since the tutorial was made, or am I making some other kind of error? The tutorial was published to YouTube on March 4th, 2020.

Comment: seems valid for 2000 https://api.census.gov/data/2000/sf1/variables/AREALAND.json but not 2010 https://api.census.gov/data/2010/sf1/variables/AREALAND.json, but let's wait for someone who knows better

Answer (score 0):

The variable for area used for 2010 data is "CSA".